# I want to print last 10 values in the list

Tags: python, list

When I have this function, I want to print last 10 values of the list. However, I don't know hot to do that.

```
import random

roll_list = [0]*13  
                #holds the number of times each number was rolled
                # has 13 spots (0 - 12).  roll_list[1] is how many times
                # a 1 was rolled.
num_rolls = 100 # number of times to roll the dice

# initialize the roll_list[] so it has the correct number of spots
def init_list():
  for _ in range(num_rolls):
    Newdice = roll_dice()
    update_list(Newdice)
    # use a for loop and list.append( x ) to fill the roll_list with 13 zeros

# returns the sum of the two dice that were rolled
def roll_dice():
  dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
  dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
  Newdice = dice1 + dice2
  return Newdice 
    # roll 2 standard die and return the sum (should be from 2 to 12)
    # random.randint() will be helpful here
    # change this line so it returns the correct sum

def update_list(Newdice): 
    roll_list[Newdice] += 1 
    # add 1 to the list location associated with the total roll value
    # example: if the total of the roll is 7, then add 1 to roll_list[7]

def print_histgram():
  for num in range(len(roll_list)):
    count = roll_list[num]
    print("{:2} {}".format(num, "*" * count)) 
    # for 100% create and print a histogram of the results of all 
    # of the dice rolls

# main program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_list()
    print_histgram()
# make a for loop that calls both roll_dice() and update_list() to roll the dice
# and update the list based on that result.  The loop should repeat the number
# of times the die are to be rolled.

# for a 90%, print the final list here
# for a 100% complete print_histogram() and call it here
```

My goals and ideal outputs

```
[0, 0, 4, 2, 7, 12, 12, 22, 12, 13, 9, 3, 4]
 0: 
 1: 
 2: ****
 3: **
 4: *******
 5: ************
 6: ************
 7: **********************
 8: ************
 9: *************
10: *********
11: ***
12: ****
```

When I used

```
print(roll_list[-10:])

The output is 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

What's wrong of this code? What code I can use? Please teach me how I can solve this functions.
I searched a lot, but the searching codes doesn't match to my functions.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code exactly as you pasted it and got:

```
 0
 1
 2 **
 3 *******
 4 *******
 5 ****
 6 **********
 7 ******************
 8 *******************
 9 *****************
10 **********
11 ***
12 ***
>>> roll_list
[0, 0, 2, 7, 7, 4, 10, 18, 19, 17, 10, 3, 3]
>>> print(roll_list[-10:])
[7, 7, 4, 10, 18, 19, 17, 10, 3, 3]
```

Perhaps when you printed `roll_list` you hadn't yet called `init_list()`?

Comment: Oh yes, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pos_cor():
    n = 10
    for i in range (n):

        x_pos = [(random.random() * box_length)]  
        y_pos = [(random.random() * box_length)]  
        z_pos = [(random.random() * box_length)] 
    
    
    
       return x_pos, y_pos, z_pos
a = x_pos, y_pos, z_pos = pos_cor()
print(a)
```